# Pandas creating combination of lists in each row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe which looks like this after some operations.

```
    x   y
0   0   [167, 171, 249, 1]
1   1   [285, 305, 291]
```

From there on I would like to make two columns and multiple rows such as this

```
    w                   z
0   [167, 171, 249]     [1]
1   [167, 171]          [249]
2   [167]               [171]
3   [285, 305]          [291]
4   [285]               [305]
```

Basically, for a given row I in the previously if the list in the cell has N values then there will be N rows in the new column W of the dataframe and in another new column Z the very last value will be placed but that part will be easy. I am more concerned first part, that is, generating N rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my suggestion is just treat the lists as lists, create a function that does what you want and iterate through the lists, something along these lines:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = [0,1]
df['y'] = [[167, 171, 249, 1], [285, 305, 291]]

def expand_list(row_list):   
    final_list = []
    final_list.append(row_list)
    n = -1
    while n> len(row_list)*-1:
        final_list.append(row_list[:n])
        n-=1
    return final_list

result_df = pd.DataFrame()
result_df['w'] = sum([expand_list(l) for l in df['y']],[])
result_df['z'] = [l[-1] for l in result_df['w']]
result_df['w'] = [l[:-1] for l in result_df['w']]
result_df = result_df[result_df.astype(str)['w'] != '[]']
```